# Sorting blocks according to values of dropdown menus in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sorting

I want **dynamically** sort the rows when dropdown menus values is changing.

Example code:                                   .

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select>
                <option selected>1</option>
                <option>2</option>
                <option>3</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>Tom</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select>
                <option>1</option>
                <option>2</option>
                <option selected>3</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>Phill</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select>
                <option>1</option>
                <option selected>2</option>
                <option>3</option>
            </select>
            <td>John</td>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

It's possible in angularjs?

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/q4gy3/1/)

Comment: you question is not clear can you provide a plunk or give us more detail by editing your question...

Comment: @wickY26, ok i made it more clear.

Comment: of course it is possible but is your data come from $scope??

Comment: @wickY26k, no, not from $scope. Data come from inputs or selects. For example: I  insert some value into input field, after that I push "sort" button and finally I must get this sorted result.

Comment: ok here is the deal, do you want to make it angular way or not if you decide to make an angular application just bind your other inputs as well... if you create a plunker I could help you better...

Comment: @wickY26, i made example on jsfiddle

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49845/discussion-between-wicky26-and-flamesoff)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I assume that you are looking an **angularjs** solution for this problem although your example is not an **angularjs** application...

Start with creating row data in our controller..

```
$scope.tableRows = [{
    select: "1",
    name: "Tom"
  }, {
    select: "2",
    name: "Phil"
  }, {
    select: "3",
    name: "John"
  }];
```

this array help us to build our table with the use of [ngRepeat](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) and here is the magic you want dynamicly sort rows depend on selection...

```
<table border="1">
    <tr ng-repeat="row in tableRows | orderBy:'select':reverse">
        <td>
            <select ng-model="row.select">
                <option>1</option>
                <option>2</option>
                <option>3</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>{{row.name}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

here is a [PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/VCe2HsDhGBKrFOZpMUxF?p=preview) for this example...

Comment: Thanks. This it what i wanted!